# C# UWP/Win2D Image Delta

Tags: c#, uwp, win2d

Let's say I've got a 256x256 source image, and several other 256x256 images that I want to compare it against programmatically to see which one is the closest to the source image. In software rendering I'd compare the RGB of each x/y pixel from the source to the corresponding destination and calculate the sum of euclidean distances to find which one has the lowest sum. That's of course very slow.

Is there a faster GPU accelerated way of doing this in Win2D?

Comment: The "solution" was I moved over to Compute Shaders on Unity3D, they are way faster. Does that constitute an answer or should I leave it open in case someone is looking for an answer specific to the question?